# Asking politely about a negative

Tags: negation

I wanted to confirm that I do **not** have an private lesson tomorrow but I'm not sure what to write. Often, negative questions as I write them seem to come off as a positive question.  Example

```
 5月9日にプライベート・レッソンの予約はありませんでしょうか？
```

That seems like it's a positive as in

```
 I have a private lesson reservation, don't I?
```

Whereas what I want to ask is

```
 I do **not** have a private lesson tomorrow right?
```

I end up guessing and wrote

```
 5月9日プライベート・レッソンを予約されてありませんでしょう。
```

Basically I just took the `か` off but something about that doesn't feel right or doesn't feel actually polite.

Note I want to effectively say "I want to confirm there is **NO** lesson, right?" and not "I want to confirm there *IS* a lesson, right?"

The difference is important because by asking the positive "There's a lesson right?" it will make people think that I believe there is a lesson and if they forgot they'd better rush to get one ready quickly.  Where as that is not my intention. My intention is to confirm there is **no lesson**.

What is the correct way to politely confirm a negative situation?

Comment: You probably mean 予約 rather than 要約 right?

Comment: _Lesson_ is レッスン. If you see someone using レッソン, they are not a native speaker.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Natural and polite expression is

```
 5月9日のプライベート・レッスンは[予約]{よやく}されていませんでしょうか？
```

The last か is required for interrogative sentence.

It doesn't feel right without the か. (especially in case of politely confirm)

Comment: And this means "I want to confirm there is NO lesson, right?" and not "I want to confirm there IS a lesson, right?" This difference is important because asking the positive "There's a lesson, right?" will make people think that I believe there is a lesson and if they forgot they'd better get one ready quickly. Where as that is not my intention. My intention is to confirm there is no lesson.

Comment: Yes I know your intention. 
To avoid misunderstanding, how about like this?
明日のレッスンは予約していない認識なのですが、間違いないでしょうか？

Comment: Thanks. Yes I kind of realized I should probably just ask in a different way. I ended up adding the "か” and then adding a clarifying question saying ”カレンダーによる今日はレッソンがないことを確認したいです。”　I guess I'd still like to know what the meaning of the original sentence is though. Is that question just a bad question because it's ambiguous?

Comment: The original sentence is almost the same meaning.
I guess there is no lesson in your calendar, and you'd like to confirm that, right?

Comment: In case of that the カレンダー is not yours but classroom's one, you can say like this.
カレンダー上で今日はレッスンがないことを確認したいです。